# Stop RavenDB Service running when I don't need it

Tags: windows, service, ravendb

I've installed the RavenDB Service on my machine. I find it's quite memory hungry and it's on a computer i use for a lot more than developing on RavenDB, so I don't really want it running all the time (I don't want it starting the service on startup).

My current approach is to run msconfig.exe and disable the service. I will then re enable it when I need RavenDB, which (annoyingly) requires a restart. I don't see RavenDB in startup tasks, so disabling it there doesn't seem to be an option.

This question may turn out to be a simple windows service type question (if so, sorry, I should have posted this on superuser), but it may be the case that more adept configuration of RavenDB is called for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like any other service, you can use the services management console to start, stop, and configure startup preferences.

Run `services.msc` or search for "Services" from your start screen.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
Raven.Server.exe /start
Raven.Server.exe /stop
```

Alternatively, run it in console mode, rather than in service mode.